# Migrating from existing Exchange 2010 server to a new server Exchange 2010

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, windows-server-2012-r2

My predecessor setup the a Exchange 2010 server with all roles and a domain controller on the same server *facepalm*. Everything is running fine but I need to raise my domain functional level from 2008 to 2012 R2. This server is the last box with a domain controller on anything older than 2012 R2.

I cant decommission the existing domain controller from the Exchange server. This could lead to disastrous results. So I am thinking I will move everything to a new Server with Exchange 2010.

My question is what unforeseen problems can I run to when installing a new exchange server with all roles installed and adding it to the Exchange organization. Everything is on the same domain. Based on what I read this seems like a pretty seamless transition if I replicate all the settings and re-point smtp, etc.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you take this opportunity to deploy Exchange 2013 while you are at it or even look at O365.

Comment: @TheCleaner 365 is planned for Q4 this year.  The reason i am doing this is to take advantage of some of the new PtH mitigation tools i can use in 2012 r2 domain level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only it was that easy.

While moving the data around is easy enough, although I will usually replicate the public folders before moving the mailboxes, getting the clients across is a lot more troublesome.

Unless you have a CAS array you are looking at either crossing your fingers that autodiscover works after removing the server completely (ie remove Exchange, DC promo out and then drop from the domain) or visiting every client to get them to update their Exchange server.

That is because even though you can move the mailbox it doesn't trigger the process to move the Exchange server in the client.

Therefore if you want to make life easier, create a CAS Array NOW, and start touching every client and repairing their Outlook profile. That will force the clients to connect to the CAS array address instead. Then when you remove the old server you can simply change the DNS entry in advance.

Everything else is just like adding an additional server - getting the SSL certificates and DNS host names in place etc.

Answer (score 0):

The process is simple and pretty straightforward. In fact, you can even choose to upgrade while at it.

Install the new exchange server (simple install with all roles), it will install an additional server into the existing organization. Create a new mailboxes database in the desired location.

- Move all mailboxes to the new server (new local move request)
- Replicate public folders (MoveAllReplicas.ps1 powershell script)
- Point the OAB to the new server
- Change the Send Connectors source server to the new server
- Make sure the receive connector has anonymous enabled
- Point the firewall (inbound 25) to the new server IP
- Uninstall exchange from the old server
- Demote